# RaisePropertyChange with Canvas

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, canvas, prism

I'm using Prism for MVVM pattern in my WP7 app. In my ViewModel I implemented two properties:

```
private IconVO _selectedIcon;
public IconVO SelectedIcon {
   get {
       return _selectedIcon;
   }
   set {
       _selectedIcon = value;
       SelectedIconCanvas = _selectedIcon.Icon;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedIcon);
   }
}

private Canvas _selectedIconCanvas;
public Canvas SelectedIconCanvas {
   get {
        return _selectedIconCanvas;
   }
   set {
       _selectedIcon = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedIconCanvas);
   }
}
```

where IconVO (it stores single icon information loaded from some XML file):

```
public class IconVO {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Canvas Icon { get; set; }
}
```

**SelectedIcon** is currently selected IconVO from `ObservableCollection<IconVO>` (collection is binded to ListPicker).

**SelectedIconCanvas** is a property which stores `Canvas` from `SelectedIcon.Icon`.

When I execute this code, application throws the **ArgumentException -> The parameter is incorrect** on this line:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedIconCanvas);
```

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks, fl4izdn4g

**EDIT 01-02-2012**

Here is XAML as you requested:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Background="{Binding SelectedColor}" >
  <ContentControl Margin="40,20,300,20" Content="{Binding SelectedIconCanvas}">
     <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ContentPresenter />
        </DataTemplate>
     </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
  </ContentControl>    
</Border>
```

I've tried to replace ContentControl with:

```
<Button Content="{Binding SelectedIconCanvas}"/>
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a UI element mentioned in a view model in MVVM. Maybe you want to reference the DataContext/view model of the selected canvas?

Comment: I've got some icons (as Canvas from ExpressionDesign) in Xaml file. I'm importing them using XamlReader which return Canvas. I want to achieve something like this:

Comment: Sorry, this is a full comment :) Stackoverflow edit policy is strange. I've got some icons (as Canvas from ExpressionDesign) in Xaml file. I'm importing them using XamlReader which returns Canvas. I want to achieve something like this: 1. user selects desired icon; 2. icon shows in bigger format. I don't want to use .png. Strange thing is that in ListPicker DataTemplate which is binded to `ObservableCollection<IconVO>` everything looks fine. I see icon and it name.

Comment: I'd make sure that canvas is only used in one place - perhaps you have it in two places in your UI and UIElements don't like having multiple parents.

Comment: Also - perhaps you could just have the property be of type string or XmlReader or whatever way your XAML vectors come in as and use IValueConverter to generate a Canvas on the fly.

Comment: great tips. It could help me. I will try implement them and I give you info.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this:

```
private IconVO _SelectedIcon;
public IconVO SelectedIcon 
{
    get { return _SelectedIcon; }
    set 
    {
       _SelectedIcon = value;
       SelectedIconCanvas = _SelectedIcon.Icon;
       RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIcon");
   }
}

private Canvas _SelectedIconCanvas;
public Canvas SelectedIconCanvas 
{
   get { return _SelectedIconCanvas; }
   set 
   {
       _SelectedIconCanvas = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIconCanvas");
   }
}
```

Sorry I changed your Properties Names (I have the C# preference)

Comment: I've tried this solution. It cause the same problem. I even tried binding without SelectedIconCanvas using something like this: **{Binding SelectedIcon.Icon}** without any luck.